# Indices of a unique vector

Tags: r, vector, indexing

I have 2 vectors in R. I can generate a vector composed of their unique elements, but I need to know the indices of each element of the vector `a`, for example :

```
 x <- c(0, 0, 2, 4, 8)
 y <- c(1, 4, 6, 6, Inf)
 a <- unique(sort(c(x, y)))

 > a
 [1]   0   1   2   4   6   8 Inf
```

I need to show that the indices of `0` (in `a`) are `x1` and `x2`, that the index of `1` is `y1`, that for `2` it is `x3`, for `4` they are `x4` and `y2` etc.

How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not name the original vectors, then use `tapply` to get what you want

```
names(x) <- paste0('x', seq_along(x))
names(y) <- paste0('y', seq_along(y))

# combine and sort
xy <- sort(c(x,y))
xy
## x1  x2  y1  x3  x4  y2  y3  y4  x5  y5 
##  0   0   1   2   4   4   6   6   8 Inf 

tapply(names(xy), xy, list)

# $`0`
# [1] "x1" "x2"
# 
# $`1`
# [1] "y1"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "x3"
# 
# $`4`
# [1] "x4" "y2"
# 
# $`6`
# [1] "y3" "y4"
# 
# $`8`
# [1] "x5"
# 
# $`Inf`
# [1] "y5"
```

Comment: Whta's the difference between paste and paste0? because I can get the same result with paste , but when I want to do it with paste0, I got this error: Error: could not find function "paste0".

Comment: Newer versions of R have paste0 which is basically a slightly faster version of paste(..., sep ="").

Answer (score 5):

```
sapply(unique(x), function(z) which(x==z)  )
```

This is pretty basic stuff and you really should be studying introduction to R and working the examples on your console.

Comment: It's just give the index of x and y seperately , but I want the index of a not x and y.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just plug `a` in place of `x` if that is what you want.

Comment: I replaced a instead of x, and it's the result: > sapply(a, function(z) which(a==z)  )
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
It's not my desire result.

Comment: `sapply(a, function(z) which(x==z) )` for the position of the `x`'s in `a` and `sapply(a, function(z) which(y==z) )` for the position of the y's.

Comment: That's good , but How can I have the result in one list instead of two , means not seperately and instead of 1 for example x[1].

Comment: +1 I voted for this too as it's a bit more elegant and easier to apply to the more general case.

Comment: Thanks. I gave up when it seemed as though the question was mutating. But perhaps the goal was always clear to the questioner but 'rose' never managed to clearly state what was the desired result

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want a function, applied over `a` which will return the name of the vector in which each element is found as well as the position in that vector.

This isn't v. pretty, but should do what you want:

```
fun1 <- function(i) {
        res <- NULL
        if (a[i] %in% x) res <- paste("x",which(x==a[i]),sep="")
        if (a[i] %in% y) res <- c(res, paste(" y",which(y==a[i]),sep=""))
        names(res) <- rep(a[i],length(res))
        return(res)
        }
```

then

```
unlist(sapply(1:length(a), FUN = fun1))
```

gives

```
    0     0     1     2     2     4     6     6     8   Inf 
 "x1"  "x2" " y1"  "x3" " y2"  "x4" " y3" " y4"  "x5" " y5"
```

**Update** is this what you're looking for?

```
fun1 <- function(i) {
    res1 <- res2 <- NULL
    if (a[i] %in% x) res1 <- paste("x", which(x %in% a[i]),sep="",collapse=" ")            
    if (a[i] %in% y) res2 <- paste("y", which(y %in% a[i]),sep="",collapse=" ")
    res <- paste(res1,res2,collapse="")
    names(res) <- a[i]
    ascii:::trim(res)
    }
```

which, with same usage as before, gives

```
      0       1       2       4       6       8     Inf 
"x1 x2"    "y1" "x3 y2"    "x4" "y3 y4"    "x5"    "y5"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could we have instead of two zero , one zero and under it "x1" and "x2", and also for 2 and 6 .

Comment: Could we have instead of two zero , one zero and under it "x1" and "x2", and also for 2 and 6 .

Comment: Could you please tell me what's ascii:::trim() ?

Comment: It's a way of accessing the function `trim()` in package namespace [`ascii`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ascii/index.html), without loading the whole package with `require(ascii)`. I put it in to make the presentation neater. You'll need to `install.packages("ascii")` if you don't have it already. Package [`stringr`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) is a more versatile choice for string manipulation.